# LINQ query to combine two string[] arrays

Tags: c#, linq

I have this case where I have two string arrays.

```
string[] array1 = new string[] { "aa", "bb", "cc"};
string[] array2 = new string[] { "abcd", "abbc", "abc", "cc", "abb" };
```

I want to use a linq query to choose only the items from `array2` that have in them any at least one item form `array1`.

So in this case I want to get in response:

```
{ "abbc", "cc", "abb" };
```

I am starting my work with linq so please give me some explanation what I am doing wrong. At this point this is my best try:

```
var res = array2.Select(n => array1.Select( c=> c.Contains(n))).ToArray();
```

But it returns:

```
array[] {array1, array1, array1, array1, array1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that by using `array1.Select(c=> c.Contains())` you were returning a collection of boolean values (contains: yes/no).

```
var res = array2.Where(x => array1.Any(y => x.Contains(y))).ToArray();
```